# antd image upload Need to convert class based component into react -hooks and unable to increase the width and height of image

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, react-redux, antd

I am facing this issue. I have attached the code and error and CodeSandbox link.

Tried to fix the issue in various methods and ways but it's not fixing.
I am not able to know why it's getting an error I don't understand the exact issue in the code. Could anyone help with the solution?

https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-darkness-g1ge3

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it to work:
https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-forest-dur6r

there were many small errors, you might want to compare with your original code to figure it out by yourself :)

Comment: getting upload error after uploading image

Comment: it's working properly on my computer, images are uploading and i see the preview in small squares.. if you post the error i can give you more help

Comment: @berin  In this code i can upload more than 4 images even after setting the length property do we need to use useReducer   {fileList.length >= 4 ? null : uploadButton} https://codesandbox.io/s/wispy-star-u4i1n

Answer (score 0):

@berin

Can u help to try that method using this method : https://github.com/JakeHartnell/react-images-upload

Need to follow this pattern

The image url in index zero of that array is the primary image.

Use a drag and drop React lib to sort the images (your choice on the React lib)

In regards to the UI, an ‘add image’ button should be displayed if there are less than four images.

There should be a delete icon overlay on each image so that a user could remove an image.                                                                          hi this need to be achived using[image: Image check it]

Comment: @brein  can u try using that above functionality